# Detemine memory used by Hazelcast cache

Tags: java, caching, memory, hazelcast

I'm implementing the backend of a game in Java and I was told to use Hazelcast to cache some data from the database. How could I find out how much memory is used by the cache (necessary to determine the business cost of this solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you buy the Hazelcast Managementcenter or you can gather the information using JMX and aggregate them on your own. Please find the JMX documentation here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#jmx-api-per-node